# jQuery UI slider step issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I got an issue with jquery-ui slider . I want to change step on different values. But I got a bug when I change step on value 1 000 000 from 50 000 to 100 000, I got 1 150 000 not 1 100 000.

```
$( function() {
    var handle = $( "#custom-handle" );
    $( "#slider-auto" ).slider({
       min : 50000,
       max : 10000000,
       step : 10000,
       create: function() {
           handle.text( $( this ).slider( "value" ) );
       },
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
           handle.text( ui.value );
           if(ui.value >= 100000 && ui.value < 1000000){
               $(this).slider('option', 'step', 50000);
           }
           else if(ui.value >= 1000000  && ui.value < 10000000){
               $(this).slider('option', 'step', 100000);
           }
       }
   });
});
```

You can see that bug here: http://test.dizajn-interiera.su/avtolombard/ , second block, first ui-slider with thousands.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a while, I just found the same *buggy* result.

I don't know the real reason of the issue, but if you set your min equal to 0, the problem is gone.

```
    ...
    else if(ui.value >= 1000000  && ui.value < 10000000){
        $(this).slider('option', 'min', 0);
        $(this).slider('option', 'step', 100000);
    }
    ...
```

I hope it could help you in some way.